# How to install java through windows command prompt?

Tags: java, automation, installation, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I was working for a testing team, where we will be testing the application End-to-End. Every time before I test I have to install the java of different version and need to uninstall the same. We tried to do this using AutoIt but we failed to Automate the installation and un-installation part of java. I hear that we can install the java through command prompt, but not sure how to do it.

I use Window greater version with different flavors of java.

Can any one help how to Install & Un-install java through command prompt, which can reduce some of the manual efforts...!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 and greater versions

Comment: I have edited the question and description. Can u please give a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install java silently you can simply make a batch file(.bat) with the following command

> **javaSetup**.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature,PublicjreFeature" INSTALLDIR=C:\Java\x86\ **javaVersion** /INSTALLDIRPUBJRE=C:\Java\x86\ **jreVersion**

A proper example for above skeleton will be

Here JDK 1.8.60 (x86) with source code is going to C:\Java\x86\jdk1.8.0_60 and JRE to C:\Java\x86\jre1.8.0_60:

```
jdk-8u60-windows-i586.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature,PublicjreFeature" INSTALLDIR=C:\Java\x86\jdk1.8.0_60 /INSTALLDIRPUBJRE=C:\Java\x86\jre1.8.0_60
```

Just make sure you keep the batch file in the same directory as your setup file